# How can I check If a nested array contains a value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have this array:

```
   var watchesArray = [
        {
          model: "FR 10", 
          image:"",
          url: "",
          price: 129.99,
          sports: ["Running", "Fitness"],
          touchScreen:false,
          GPS:false,
          heartRateMonitor:false,
          hrZoneTraining:false,
        },
    ];

    if(watchesArray[0].sports(contains a specific value or values){
      do something
    } else {
       dont do anything
    }
```

And all I want to do is check whether this watch has a specific sport and if it does then put it in an if statement so that I can do something with it.

How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: It's just an array, even if it's "nested": `watchesArray[0].sports.indexOf('Running') !== -1` Note that this returns `0` if it's the first index, so you have to check for `-1` (which is "not found").

Comment: Have you tried [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [*Array.indexOf*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) like bellow

```
if(watchesArray[0].sports.indexOf('Running') > -1){
    do somwthing
}
```

**NOTE:-** In case of if parents doesn't exist it'll throw error.

Answer (score 1):

It's just an array, even if it's "nested":

```
if (watchesArray[0].sports.indexOf('Running') !== -1) ...
```

This returns `0` if it's the first index, so you have to check for `-1` (which is "not found").

Note that IE7/8 did not support [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), but there are ways to [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/atk/1034425) that if needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one simple function which supported in all browsers but you can write the following code:

```
function contains(a, obj) {
    var i = a.length;
    while (i--) {
       if (a[i] === obj) {
           return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

For more details you look in this answer
[How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can try indexof like this:

```
var watchesArray = [
                     {
                       model: "FR 10", 
                       image:"",
                       url: "",
                       price: 129.99,
                       sports: ["Running", "Fitness"],
                       touchScreen:false,
                       GPS:false,
                       heartRateMonitor:false,
                       hrZoneTraining:false,
                     },
                 ];

 if (watchesArray[0].sports.indexOf('hello') != -1){
                     alert("exists");
                 } else {
                     alert("this index does not exist");
                 }
```

for array in javascript you can always traverse using the key specified. if the key does not exists indexof will return 0 so it will go to the else part.

Answer (score 0):

As Jared mentioned you can use [Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

> The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

In your case it would mean

```
if(watchesArray[0].sports.indexOf(value) !== -1){
  do something
} else {
   dont do anything
}
```

I also provided you a little function to match multiple values: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nuvuda/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can also use Includes.

```
if(watchesArray[0].sports.includes('Running'))
{
    // Exists
}
else{
    // Doesn't exist
}
```

This is not always supported though so check that you browser [supports it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#browser_compatibility).